# Customize primary key autogenerate function in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In an Ecto schema, it's possible to specify an autogenerated primary key by using the `@primary_key` attribute:

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
```

Is there a way to specify a custom function to `autogenerate`? I believe in this case it would use `Ecto.UUID.generate`, whereas I'd like to use a v1 UUID.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the official documentation](https://phoenixframework.org/blog/custom-primary-key), you can create your own custom primary key.

Here is a quick example to set `name` as the primary key:

let's say we generated a `Player` table with the following mix task :

`mix phoenix.gen.json Player players name:string position:string number:integer`

in your migration, set `create table` with `primary_key: false` and add `primary_key: true` to the name field :

```
  def change do
    create table(:players, primary_key: false) do
      add :name, :string, primary_key: true
      add :position, :string
      add :number, :integer

      timestamps
    end
  end
```

Then in your schema, all you have to do is tell Ecto that the primary key is now a string (`@primary_key {:name, :string, []}`) and that the ID to be used (e.g. in the routes) will be `name` `@derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :name}`. Also don't forget to remove `field :name, :string`.

```
defmodule Hello.Player do
  use Hello.Web, :model

  @primary_key {:name, :string, []}
  @derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :name}
  schema "players" do
    field :position, :string
    field :number, :integer

    timestamps
  end
```

What you can do in your case is to set up your own field  as the primary key, then populate it in a changeset with a method that generates an ID with v1 UUID, when you persist your data in your database.

You can take advantage of [the UUID package](https://hexdocs.pm/uuid/readme.html) that has a UUID v1 method.

Not sure whether it is the best workaround solution, but I hope It helps you :)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I know I can set a custom ID in each changeset, but since this is something I'd want to do for all schemas in all changsets that create a new record, I'm hoping to find a way to configure a custom ID generation function in one place for everything …

Comment: @FeifanZ have you found a better solution to this problem ? I am curious about how you handled this :)

Comment: I haven't found a better solution to this particular problem, but found an alternative approach instead. Originally, I was thinking I need a v1 UUID for sorting, but it turns out that I don't strictly need that, so a v4 UUID is ok.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is my solution

```elixir
#Custom string type (example of Ecto.UUID)
defmodule Ecto.UUID.AutoGenerate do
  use Ecto.Type
  def type, do: :string
  def cast(uuid), do: {:ok, uuid}
  def dump(uuid), do: {:ok, uuid}
  def load(uuid), do: {:ok, uuid}
  def autogenerate, do: Ecto.UUID.generate() # <- update your version here
end
# In your schema
defmodule PosService.Weathers.Weather do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  @primary_key {:id, Ecto.UUID.AutoGenerate, autogenerate: true}
  @foreign_key_type :string
  schema "weathers" do
    field :city, :string
    field :prcp, :float
    field :temp_hi, :integer
    field :temp_lo, :integer
    timestamps()
  end
end
```